# Gulp remove .min.* from filenames

Tags: gulp

I have the following array of files

```
  var jqueryFiles=[
                    'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
                    'bower_components/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js',
                    'bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js'
                  ]
```

What I want to achieve is to move them into the folder `web/assets/vendor` but with their names not have the `.min.` before js eg.

I want to move the `'bower_components/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js` into the `web/assets/vendor/jquery.slimscroll.js` file

Any ideas?

Comment: if you remove the "min" then how will you know they are miniifed files? seems like an odd case. Why are you doing this?

Comment: I want to do because later I want choose whether to load the minified or unminified depending if I am on development or not.

Comment: traditionally that functionality would be provided by writing the script tags to be with min or not. Of course you are free to it how you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [gulp-ext-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ext-replace) to do that. If in development, you can specify the code like this

```
var ext_replace = require('gulp-ext-replace');
 gulp.src("file.js").pipe(ext_replace('.min.js', '.js')).pipe(gulp.dest(tagrget)
```

Comment: You have an error it should be ` gulp.src("file.min.js").pipe(ext_replace('.js', '.min.js')).pipe(gulp.dest(tagrget))`

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas: Oh sorry. It may be a typo while posting the answer. Thanks. and will update my answer.